# Police Cars won't spawn in Watch Dogs?

Tags: watch-dogs

I know where the police station is, I drive past there all the time to look for police cars but they are never there. Is this because i'm using a PS3? All the videos i've seen have been on PC and PS4.

Is there any other place to find police cars?

Comment: Is this the police station you're talking about? http://i.stack.imgur.com/XW3PZ.jpg

Comment: Are you trying to find a police car?

Comment: So what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Chippies, thats the police station yeah, there is nothing there

Comment: Have you tried reloading the game and going there again? If nothing still spawns, perhaps someone with a ps3/xbox360 copy of the game can confirm that the specific police station parking lot is indeed empty. I can see the last gen consoles having some stuff cut from the game as opposed to current gen and PC versions, but Idk if this is case in particular is an isolated case or it is indeed a limitation imposed by the devs.

Comment: You could call the police by waving a gun around and firing a few shots near civs. They will call the cops, and you can jack the car and hide. More difficult, but it's a way to work around the problem :3

Answer (score 1):

I did this on Xbox and it works maybe try driving a long way and back 1-5 times

Answer (score 0):

PS3: **(May work on other platforms)** *Clarification?*

Police cars will spawn right after Act 2 - Mission 16 and after you do all online options.
I did this, and I got police cars and SUVs